# Magento Multiwebsite Configuration Setup

Tags: magento

I am using multi website magento store having 3 websites for books,electronics and apparels in subdirectories like `www.example.com/books`, `www.example.com/apparels`. Is it necessary to include all folders like app, downloader, skin, etc in root folder to subdirectories or any other option is there because it seems to consume more memory for each one.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to.

You can create multiple stores from `system -> Manage Stores -> Create Store`, if you don't have them already.

You can manage the url of the stores from `system -> configuration -> Web` and set secure and unsecure base url for each store by selecting the configuration scope on the top left.

E.g.: You can select the scope to 'books' store and set base url to `www.example.com/books` and set the scope to 'apparels' store and set base url to `www.example.com/apparels`.

Edit:

You also have to copy the index.php to the subfolder and edit this file. E.g. for `www.example.com/apparels`, add:

```
$mageRunCode = 'apparels';
$mageRunType = 'website';
```

before the line:

```
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Also try to copy the `.htaccess` to the subdirectory.

Comment: Hi I did like this which you mentioned above but it shows C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_store\apparels/app/Mage.php was not found... If I copy the remaining folders app,skin,etc from root folder and paste it into apparels folder its working fine..

Comment: Edited my answer. Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

I manage one Magento site with two stores (two totally different URLs) operating from one instance of Magento. Each URL points to a different base directory on the hosting site. One directory holds the entire Magento installation. The second directory uses a combination of symbolic links and actual files as follows.

Symbolic links: app, errors, includes, js, media, skin, var

Actual files: .htaccess, index.php

www-root/directory1/[all magento files]

www-root/directory2/[symbolic links and .htaccess and index.php files]

You then set the insecure and secure base URLs for each store. In this case there is a separate root category for each store. And many of the Magento configuration parameters may be set individually for each store or use the default value.

Comment: Hi I was not able to create symbolic links. Then I moved to system->configuration->Web and selected current config scope as apparels and then changed the base url as http://localhost/magento/apparels/,base skin url as http://localhost/magento/skin/,base media url as http://localhost/magento/media/ and then it works fine

Answer (score 0):

No, you no need to copy all folder , you need to create folder for books & apparels then copy your index.php and .htaccess file from magento root folder to existing folder (both books & apparels) also you need to set base url in magento adminpanel > system > configuration > web for new stores